# How can I use app2sd+ on Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, app2sd

My phone is a very old one (HTC Desire). I recently find a 4.4 ROM which descriped by this post [Update HTC Desire to Android 4.4.2 KitKat with j00m ROM](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/update-htc-desire-android-4-4-2-kitkat-j00m-rom/). Then I followed the author's step and upgrade my Android ROM successfully. Everything runs more quickly and smoothly. But the inner storage is very little to install new apps (beside system files, only about 140Mb for app and 80Mb left).

So I tried to use the app2sd+ method on Android 2.3. I moved `/data/app` and `/data/app-private` to `/sd-ext/` with soft link, everything is OK now. But after I moved `/data/dalvik-cache` to `/sd-ext/` and run reboot, system can never boot up more.

So I wonder is there any other way to free the limited inner storage to my ext3 partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searched a lot of posts from Google, I have worked it out.

Just use this command under adb shell instead of manual moving and creating soft link:

```
$ a2sd install
y
n
y
```

Done! This works perfectly!